# create the postGIS table error No such driver: PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, r

I'm trying to create the postGIS table with spatial features I can do it by:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(spacetime)
library(rgdal)
dbname = "geodatabase"
user = "postgres"
password = "***"
#password = ""

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname=dbname, user=user, password=password,host='localhost', port='5432')

data(air)
rural = as(rural, "STSDF")
p = rural@sp
sp = SpatialPointsDataFrame(p, data.frame(geom_id=1:length(p)))

OGRstring = paste("PG:dbname=", dbname, " user=", user," password=", password, " host=localhost"," port=5432",sep = "")

print(OGRstring)
writeOGR(sp, OGRstring, "rural_space", driver = "PostgreSQL")
```

I look for is how the error:

```
 > source('~/R/postgres/myScript.R')
[1] "PG:dbname=geodatabase user=postgres password=zina host=localhost port=5432"
Error in writeOGR(sp, OGRstring, "rural_space", driver = "PostgreSQL") : 
  No such driver: PostgreSQL
```

please help me

EDIT:

```
 > ogrDrivers()
             name write
1      AeronavFAA FALSE
2          ARCGEN FALSE
3          AVCBin FALSE
4          AVCE00 FALSE
5             BNA  TRUE
6             CSV  TRUE
7             DGN  TRUE
8             DXF  TRUE
9          EDIGEO FALSE
10 ESRI Shapefile  TRUE
11     Geoconcept  TRUE
12        GeoJSON  TRUE
13       Geomedia FALSE
14         GeoRSS  TRUE
15            GML  TRUE
16            GMT  TRUE
17       GPSBabel  TRUE
18  GPSTrackMaker  TRUE
19            GPX  TRUE
20            HTF FALSE
21         Idrisi FALSE
22            KML  TRUE
23   MapInfo File  TRUE
24         Memory  TRUE
25   MSSQLSpatial  TRUE
26           ODBC  TRUE
27            ODS  TRUE
28        OpenAir FALSE
29    OpenFileGDB FALSE
30         PCIDSK  TRUE
31            PDF  TRUE
32            PDS FALSE
33         PGDump  TRUE
34           PGeo FALSE
35            REC FALSE
36            S57  TRUE
37           SDTS FALSE
38       SEGUKOOA FALSE
39           SEGY FALSE
40            SUA FALSE
41            SVG FALSE
42            SXF FALSE
43          TIGER  TRUE
44        UK .NTF FALSE
45            VRT FALSE
46           Walk FALSE
47           WAsP  TRUE
48           XLSX  TRUE
49         XPlane FALSE
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] spacetime_1.1-0 sp_1.0-15       RPostgreSQL_0.4 DBI_0.2-7      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.0       intervals_0.14.0 lattice_0.20-29  rgeos_0.3-6      tools_3.1.0     
[6] xts_0.9-7        zoo_1.7-11
```

Edit:

code R:

```
writeOGR(sp, "C:/file.sql", "rural_space", driver = "PGDump")
```

code psql via cmd.exe

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\zina>cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin>psql -h localhost -d geodatabase -U postgres
 -f "C:\file.sql"
SET
psql:C:/file.sql:2: ERREUR:  la table « rural_space » n'existe pas
DELETE 0
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
                      addgeometrycolumn
--------------------------------------------------------------
 public.rural_space.wkb_geometry SRID:4326 TYPE:POINT DIMS:2
(1 ligne)


CREATE INDEX
ALTER TABLE
psql:C:/file.sql:9: ERREUR:  la colonne « OGC_FID » de la relation « rural_space
 » n'existe pas
LIGNE 1 : ...ERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" ...
                                                               ^
psql:C:/file.sql:10: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:11: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:12: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:13: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:14: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:15: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:16: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:17: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:18: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:19: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:20: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:21: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:22: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:23: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:24: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:25: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:26: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:27: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:28: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:29: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:30: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:31: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:32: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:33: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:34: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:35: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:36: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:37: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:38: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:39: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:40: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:41: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:42: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:43: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:44: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:45: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:46: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:47: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:48: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:49: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:50: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:51: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:52: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:53: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:54: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:55: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:56: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:57: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:58: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:59: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:60: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:61: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:62: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:63: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:64: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:65: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:66: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:67: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:68: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:69: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:70: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:71: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:72: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:73: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:74: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:75: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:76: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:77: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
psql:C:/file.sql:78: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ign
orées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction
ROLLBACK
```

file.sql :

```
SET standard_conforming_strings = OFF;
DROP TABLE "public"."rural_space" CASCADE;
DELETE FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name = 'rural_space' AND f_table_schema = 'public';
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "public"."rural_space" ( OGC_FID SERIAL, CONSTRAINT "rural_space_pk" PRIMARY KEY (OGC_FID) );
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','rural_space','wkb_geometry',4326,'POINT',2);
CREATE INDEX "rural_space_wkb_geometry_geom_idx" ON "public"."rural_space" USING GIST ("wkb_geometry");
ALTER TABLE "public"."rural_space" ADD COLUMN "geom_id" INTEGER;
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000BABBCE86FC2B2340B1524145D5D54A40', 0 , 1);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000C98E8D40BC5E2340D09B8A5418C34A40', 1 , 2);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000E012807F4A952340ADDBA0F65B094B40', 2 , 3);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000772CB649454B2B405A643BDF4F394A40', 3 , 4);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000009A249694BB972A402235ED629A534A40', 4 , 5);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000F435CB65A3732A401684F23E8E3C4A40', 5 , 6);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000F530B43A39DB2140E67805A227B74940', 6 , 7);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000828B1535986621407978CF81E56C4A40', 7 , 8);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000897956D28A7F1B407593180456EE4940', 8 , 9);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000B05417F0327B244038F4160FEF0B4B40', 9 , 10);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000006762BA10AB6F2A40B9347EE195684840', 10 , 11);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000037894160E5382940CD052E8F35374940', 11 , 12);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000077D66EBBD0042A4063B83A00E2A64940', 12 , 13);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000DC9F8B868C371C4050E3DEFC86E14840', 13 , 14);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000006971C63027C02440363B527DE7474940', 14 , 15);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000060CD0182399A2140670FB40243EA4A40', 15 , 16);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000BF29AC5450E92C409F1D705D31154A40', 16 , 17);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000DF4F8D976EA22140520ABABDA4D34840', 17 , 18);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000006F2F698CD6B92640AAF06778B3A64A40', 18 , 19);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000042942F6821212840423EE8D9ACE84A40', 19 , 20);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000EF54C03DCF072C408AABCABE2B484A40', 20 , 21);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000BF4692205C811F4007EBFF1CE6174B40', 21 , 22);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000F75965A6B4E62140DD4598A25CEA4940', 22 , 23);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000006A12BC218D522740C37E4FAC53654940', 23 , 24);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000078EFA83121C61C407E18213CDADE4840', 24 , 25);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000009A7D1EA33C0B214064744012F6DB4840', 25 , 26);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000042226DE34F2C2B40B97020240B6A4940', 26 , 27);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000D3FA5B02F09F24408DD2A57F49B24940', 27 , 28);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000E085ADD9CA832C40E5805D4D9EC24A40', 28 , 29);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000005131CEDF84922D40787B1002F2694940', 29 , 30);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000003B1BF2CF0CDA2940FEB7921D1BC34940', 30 , 31);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000009A42E73576712740C9586DFE5F294940', 31 , 32);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000001EFB592C45622040CC46E7FC14774940', 32 , 33);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000081EDFDE35102A40A165DD3F16924A40', 33 , 34);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000007C7DAD4B8D002240F302ECA353354940', 34 , 35);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000046EC134031021C40D2AC6C1FF2D04840', 35 , 36);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000C939B187F6812140B9E00CFE7EBB4840', 36 , 37);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000009FEB7921DDB1C40166A4DF38EDB4A40', 37 , 38);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000363B527DE7772940A7E7DD5850584A40', 38 , 39);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000030D461855B4E1F40D0285DFA97A24840', 39 , 40);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000E2E6543200BC254012691B7FA2AA4940', 40 , 41);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000043A9336553F2A40156F641EF93D4A40', 41 , 42);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000E1455F419A592B409241EE224C8F4940', 42 , 43);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000020B24813EF382640581AF8510DF34740', 43 , 44);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000008C67D0D01F2840753FA7203F274940', 44 , 45);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000008257CB9D99082140A3772AE09EE94840', 45 , 46);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000D55C6E30D4A11F40BA675DA3E5F44740', 46 , 47);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000B262B83A008A254078B6476FB8534940', 47 , 48);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000D4449F8F324A2B402B685A62657C4A40', 48 , 49);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000005C3E92921EEE2A4024F25D4A5D544940', 49 , 50);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000058CA32C4B10E1F40386A85E97BE74740', 50 , 51);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000029AF95D05D6A22408BFCFA21362C4840', 51 , 52);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000005C1C959BA8CD2540F1D58EE21CEF4A40', 52 , 53);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000008C67D0D01F1940F148BC3C9D534940', 53 , 54);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000049A0C1A6CE4B204053910A630BC94940', 54 , 55);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000F8E12021CA2723406891ED7C3FE14940', 55 , 56);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000006556EF703B242C40AF7B2B1213DE4A40', 56 , 57);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000A29BFD817283254018CFA0A17F664A40', 57 , 58);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000FFEA71DF6A1D2C4068AED3484B454A40', 58 , 59);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000006823D74D29DF234003EE79FEB43F4940', 59 , 60);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000632B685A622523405B5EB9DE36714840', 60 , 61);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000F697DD938755264018CFA0A17F7A4A40', 61 , 62);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000006D8D08C6C1851940D7A6B1BD16224940', 62 , 63);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000002CBB6070CD9D20402B685A6265764B40', 63 , 64);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000008D0DDDEC0FE41F40A01A2FDD24624940', 64 , 65);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E610000045A0FA07912C1D40F1D8CF6229B64840', 65 , 66);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000007DE882FA9639254053910A630BE14940', 66 , 67);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E6100000B37A87DBA1712940D9EBDD1FEF374B40', 67 , 68);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000008D28ED0DBE802B40CBD6FA22A15D4940', 68 , 69);
INSERT INTO "public"."rural_space" ("wkb_geometry" , "OGC_FID" , "geom_id") VALUES ('0101000020E61000001DCC26C0B0E422401FF30181CE9E4840', 69 , 70);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: The last fix to `file.sql` is to edit `"OGC_FID"` to `OGC_FID` (remove quotes). It can be done with search->replace in most text editors. This is a simple bug in the driver, which I think is fixed for the next version of GDAL/OGR.

Comment: Which version should I use gdal / ogr ,I installed this version http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-11-0-mapserver-6-4-1.zip, is still the problem persists, I don't understand please help

Comment: That's a separate installation of GDAL/OGR. The version used by `rgdal` is `rgdal.dll`, which has a bug, so the file needs to be edited as suggested above. Did the edits work?

Comment: yes it works with the changes you have made ​​me, but I want to add the Postgresql driver,it's not available in the ogrDrivers() list ,how to ad it?  it was just an example to show you the Postgresql driver does not exist

Comment: look at my real problem here :http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111181/import-shapefiles-on-my-postgis-table-using-r/111192?noredirect=1#comment157787_111192

Comment: The *only* way to add a `PostgreSQL` driver is to compile the `rgdal` package, which is not an easy thing to do. The `PGDump` option is by far the simplest option, even if it isn't perfect. As I mentioned before, I encourage you to contact the maintainer to kindly ask support for the `PostgreSQL` driver.

Comment: :( what should I do in your opinion? I'm stuck for a week for this error. is that you have to follow a tutorial please?

Comment: Is your only geometry type `Point`? If so, then yes there are easier options..

Comment: who is the maintaine can you give me the link of the contact please?

Comment: All contact info here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/

Comment: thank you very much, I'll let you know the result, thank you for your time, respect

Answer (score 2):

Do you see "PostgreSQL" with `ogrDrivers()`? If not, then your version of `rgdal` and GDAL/OGR was not configured to support the [PostgreSQL driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html).

If you didn't compile any of these components and used [the binaries of `rgdal` from CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/), you may want to kindly ask Roger, the maintainer, if it could be supported for a future release of the binary for your platform (e.g., send info from `sessionInfo()`).

---

A workaround is to use the [PGDump](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgdump.html) driver to write an SQL file that can be loaded into a PostgreSQL database:

```
writeOGR(sp, "C:/path/to/file.sql", "rural_space", driver = "PGDump")
```

Then load this file into PostgreSQL using one of many ways, including from cmd.exe:

```
psql -h localhost -d geodatabase -U postgres -f "C:\path\to\file.sql"
```

Comment: I installed R Version 3.1.1 then I got back green R 3.1.0, that's why this problem perssiste although I uninstalled R 3.1.1 What is the solution according to you?

Comment: @zina_GIS you don't have the "PostgreSQL" driver, and it isn't easy to add since it needs to be compiled. A workaround is to use the "PGDump" driver, then load this file in separately.

Comment: I edited my post to see the error I got after applying what you've told me help please?