# Writeogr to PostgreSQL/PostGIS database with R

Tags: postgis, postgresql, r, ogr, rgdal

I'm producing some Spatialpolygondataframes with R that I would like to upload to my PostGIS Database. I've found out that the way to do this is via the [`writeOGR()`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgdal/docs/writeOGR) function using the [PostgreSQL driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html).

Sadly, my version of rgdal and GDAL/OGR doesn't support the PostgreSQL function (as seen when listing the available drivers using `ogrDrivers()`). Is there a way to make this driver available? My `sessionInfo()` is as follows:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

[...]

other attached packages:
rgdal_1.1-10
gdalUtils_2.0.1.7
RPostgreSQL_0.4-1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** :

As of 2021, the preferred solution would be to use the [{sf}](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/index.html) package, even when using {sp} classes :

```
library(sf)
library(RPostgres)

con <- dbConnect(Postgres(), user = "PG_USER", password = "PG_PASS", host = "192.0.2.0",dbname = "dbname")
st_write(st_as_sf(my_layer), con, Id(schema = "public", table = "my_layer"))
```

---

**Former answer** :

The package [PostGIStools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/postGIStools/index.html) can help. See for example the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/postGIStools/vignettes/postGIStools-vignette.html).

Another way could be to transform your Spatial*DataFrame geometry to WKT, insert into PostGIS using the classic RPostgreSQL package and re-create the geom there.

Comment: I've tried the first method and it works like a charm using the `postgis_insert()` command (in case you want to includ this in your answer). If you will allow me a followup question: Do you know how do address a schema with the `postgis_insert()` command?

Answer (score 5):

If this is still relevant, at the University of Florida, David Bucklin and I have released a [rpostgis](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rpostgis) package that provides bi-directional transfer between PostGIS and R for vector and raster data. The package does not rely on GDAL (and rgdal), and should be platform independent.

Assuming that a functional connection can be established through `RPostgreSQL`, here is a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates its use with respect to the original question (upload a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to PostGIS). Specifically, using the low resolution map of the world from `rworldmap`:

```
library(rpostgis)
conn <- dbConnect(drv = "PostgreSQL", host = "localhost", dbname = "rpostgis", user = "postgres", password = "postgres_password")

library("rworldmap")
world <- getMap()
pgInsert(conn, "world", world, new.id = "gid")
```

Note that the `new.id` argument will create a new column name for a sequential ID ("gid"). To retrieve the data back into R as a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, use `pgGetGeom`:

```
world.db <- pgGetGeom(conn, "world")
```

Comment: Thank you for joining and answering.  But please don't post duplicate answers in multiple threads: either vary your posts in meaningful ways or else select one thread for your answer.

Comment: Who is the "we" you refer to?  Please disclose your affiliation as required in [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Fair points, I apologize for cross-posting and keeping my answer minimal. As some of the initial questions were fairly outdated, my proposition may not be relevant any more for the OP… hence the brevity. I'd be happy to provide more details if this still makes sense.

Comment: As for who's we, that's me (Mathieu Basille) and David Bucklin, both authors of the R package `rpostgis`. I also understand that it looks like shameless advertising, but I really meant to be useful: the package (which is open-source with exactly no benefits generated from it) was developed to provide exactly what the (various) OP originally asked for, namely to provide bi-directional transfer between PostGIS and R for vector and raster data.

Comment: Please let me know if you'd find it appropriate that I try to adjust my answer to each initial question.

Comment: I don't understand the negative critic and downvotes. It seems your package solves exactly the issue I had in my original question. The issue isn't relevant to me currently, but I'll definitely will get back to this solution as soon as it does.

Comment: As to their defense, they are raising fair points to protect the integrity of Stack Exchange. I could have done a much better job at presenting the package and its use — which I just did, to demonstrate how `rpostgis` answers your initial question.

Comment: This is a perfect valid answer (+1); and I am glad you have understood how this site works; i.e. avoid only recommending a tool/software, but explain why and how it works. Reproducible examples are always great too. Also, take a look at: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4512/tag-requested-for-odl-studio-questions/4514#4514.

Comment: @MathieuBasille Hi, how to insert Spatial* object with attribute columns? For instance,  we have a record, i.e. a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object and some attributes (country and city), so we need two add two additional columns. How to handle it?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand… `pgInsert` should take care of a Spatial*DataFrame. If you already have it created in the database, then you need to match column names. Open a new question and/or an issue for the package if that does not work properly.