# import SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (SPDF) into PostgreSQL DB schema from R

Tags: postgis, postgresql, r

This is a followup question to
[Writeogr to PostgreSQL/PostGIS database with R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195156/writeogr-to-postgresql-postgis-database-with-r)

How can I choose the schema where to put the SPDF (or any other spatial object)?

```
postgis_insert(con, df=catchments, tbl="land_use", geom_name="st_astext")
```

I can't just type `schema1.land_use` in the `tbl` argument and there is no further argument to assign the schema. It seems that I can only put it into the public schema of the DB (which is kind of the default schema in PostgreSQL)

Comment: It doesn't look like you can directly, as dbConnect does not contain an option for schema. You can always change the database search_path order in Postgres first, and then the table inserted into will be the one that matches the first schema in the search path. `ALTER DATABASE foo SET  search_path to bar, public, etc....` See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html I accept that this is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is also posible. I finished by adding a line of code in R which changes the schema in the DB `dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE land_use SET SCHEMA spatial;")` So, I don't have to change to PostgreSQL

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. I think that dbconnect aims to be generic and different databases have different concepts about what a schema is?

Comment: I guess so, though I've only worked with PostgreSQL. Maybe they will include this feature in the RPostgreSQL in the future.